# Adding an obstacle in Google map API

Tags: google-maps, polygon, jquery-waypoints

I have a polygon of a particular area,( this is an obstacle). When i give the start point and end piont it should not pass this polygon and should give a new route.

Any idea apart from adding waypoints of that particular polygon ?

Thanks.

Comment: why the tag [tag:jquery-waypoints]? Did you really mean this plugin? http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/